# How can I use "getopts" without a parameter? (here for "-v")

Tags: shell, parameters

How can I use the `getopts` without a parameter?

```
while getopts ":a:f:l:r:h:v:" arg; do
   printf $arg
   case $arg in
     a)
        add_param=${OPTARG}
        ;;
     f)
        file_param=${OPTARG}
        ;;
     l)
        list_param=${OPTARG}
        ;;
     r)
       remove_param=${OPTARG}
       ;;
     v)
       version_param="version"
       printf "hello world"
       ;;
     h | *)
       print_usage
       exit_script
   esac
done
```

I never get in the case `-v` if I run my script like this `sh script.sh -v` because this implementation expects a parameter.

Can you help me to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help getopts` (in `bash`):

> ```
> getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
>     Parse option arguments.
>
>     Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters
>     as options.
>
>     OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
>     is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
>     which should be separated from it by white space.
> ```

I think it's valid also for `sh`. You should try `":a:f:l:r:hv"` instead of `":a:f:l:r:h:v:"`.

Comment: How would you use it in a script? Say you have "b" that doesn't have an argument, how would your script know that "-b" was on the command line since it doesn't have an argument?

Comment: @majorgear This looks like a separate question. [Ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask); include a link to this answer if you think it provides context.